# Microsoft XACT - How to preserve window & column width

Tags: windows-10, audio

While using [Microsoft XACT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-platform_Audio_Creation_Tool) I have grown increasingly frustrated with the application not remembering my preferred column and window width. Anyone who works with these type of applications knows that it is a pain to have to manually resize things to our liking EVERY TIME we open a project.

[image]

So far I have tried the usual Windows sizing tricks:

- held <kbd>CTRL</kbd> while resizing
- held <kbd>ALT</kbd> while resizing
- held <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> while resizing

None of these seemed to work. I know already about the arrangement of the workspace via the Window menu, and while this feature is slightly handy, it does not address the issue of column width (which is important if we want to read our notes).

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: There is no generic solution, it would require the program to be modified to track such things. But we are talking about niche software that is long obsolete. You could maybe try asking Microsoft to release it as open source but it's not likely to happen. Really you are best to either live with it or look for a modern alternative

Comment: The software is a unique, and as you mentioned, an antiquated thing, however there are no other programs that can do with this does with its SDK integration for some games. I thought perhaps there was something I missed. Still hoping there is an XACT guru out there that might know a few tricks!